# Sporadic brief yet massive drops in bandwidth

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, bandwidth

One office internet connection I use regularly has decent average bandwidth (around 40M up/40M down typically).

However, it commonly has brief drops in bandwidth. These typically last for 0.5-5 seconds, and are incredibly painful during audio/video/screensharing sessions, since it causes gaps and delays.

An example speedtest graph of this is shown below. Note the green graph showing the download bandwidth over the duration of the test, and how it dropped from over 40M to near zero in the second quarter of the test, and then went back above 40M during the second half of the test.

Is there any chance this issue is due to network equipment on my end?

If so, are there any reasonable steps to explore or diagnose it?

If not, is there any reasonable method of action to improve it? (There is only one ISP I can get in the building)

[image: speedtest results]

Answer (score 0):

There are a large number of potential causes of the problem.    I'd suggest a 2 prong approach

1. Try plugging your devices in with a cable and see if that solves the problem.  If it does
   then you need to target the wireless path (which is more likely where the cause is but
   harder to work out).  If not you need to check your LAN, then your gateway and then 
   the wider Internet.
2. If the problem is with the Wireless side then things get interesting.  It could be
   the router trying to negotiate a new/better channel, it could be related to the firmware
   and other processes happening in the router, it could be periodic interference from 
   an external device.    Trying alternative routers and also see if moving closer to
   the router/Access point fixes your problems.   You might want to try something like
   DD-WRT if your router supports it - lots of router firmware is buggy and DD-WRT is
   often more stable.   If your router is set to negotiate frequencies you may want to
   try turning off auto negotiation.

In both cases using something like MTR or WinMTR will help isolate the culprit by showing where packets stop flowing for a time.

Definitely though, start by running WINMTR or equivalent to a known site (example www.google.com) for a reasonable period - and switch to it during the outages to see if that helps you work out if its on the WIFI (first hop) or further down the track.